# mysql encoding problem

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

i have a proble, when insert something in foreign language into database.
i have set the collation of database to utf8_general_ci(try utf8_unicod_ci too). 
but when i insert some text into table, it was saved like this

### **Õ€Õ¡ÕµÕ¥Ö€Õ¥Õ¶ Ô±Õ¶Õ¸Ö‚Õ¶**

but when i read from database, text shows in correct form. it looks like that only in database.

i have set encoding in my html document to charset=UTF-8

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

and i set

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF-8");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET UTF-8");
```

when conecting to database. 
so i think that i' ve done everything, but it still save in that anknown format.
could you help me.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have to `SET NAMES utf8`, instead of `UTF-8`, in MySQL.

Comment: i don't ubderstand. rewrite please

Comment: Try mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like maybe your phpmyadmin isn't using the correct charset. In your phpmyadmin folder, open config.default.php and edit the lines

```
$cfg['DefaultCharset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'en-iso-8859-1';
```

To your chosen encoding.

Comment: @adam can i do that by some functions?( like ini.set() in php), because i haven't permission to change them on the hosting!

Comment: I don't think so. It should pick up the encoding automatically (and correctly). You could contact your host or install your own copy.

Comment: @adam but there isn't any config.default.php file. only config.inc.php and config.sample.inc.php.

Comment: @adam there aren't such thing in both of them:(

Comment: Ok. If it's there, it might be under a different name. It's really not my area, so you'll have to have a look about

Answer (score 0):

It is suggested to use [`mysql_set_charset()`](http://lv.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php)  instead of "SET NAMES" query, however the impact should be the same.

Comment: @naivists what is the difference?